# Append only records where to columns criteria match

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to do a query but unsure how to do it - I have searched the internet and the site but to no avail

We receive data in a very unusual format, and we cant request to have it changed either. The data may change columns daily and we have 250 columns of data

I want a query to search the columns and if for example column 3 and 4 have 110 in them, then I want that record to append to a new table

The two columns I need to compare will always be next to each other, but can be anywhere within the 250 columns

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In what form do you receive the data - Excel, csv, dbf? You set a link to the source? The column names are always the same? Did you mean append to an **existing** table? Are the fields all in the same order in the link table and local table design? Consider:

`INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Field3=110 AND Field4=110`

Otherwise, probably need VBA procedure.